# Auto-keyframing fails to record when a modal timer op is setting position/rotation?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes

I have a serious problem in understanding how the Modal Operator works. I created a Python script using the Modal Operator Timer template, which basically translates and rotates the camera of the scene taking data from a sensor. The function called is:

```
def get_rotation(self):
        data = tracker.get_data()
        print("Received:\n%r" % data)
        try:
            camera.rotation_quaternion[0] = data[3]
            camera.rotation_quaternion[1] = data[4]
            camera.rotation_quaternion[2] = data[5]
            camera.rotation_quaternion[3] = data[6]

            camera.rotation_quaternion.rotate(math_rot_x)
            camera.rotation_quaternion.rotate(math_rot_z)

            camera.location[0] = data[0]
            camera.location[1] = -data[2]
            camera.location[2] = data[1]
        except KeyError:
            raise ExitOK
```

And this function is called here:

```
def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            print("Vive Tracker to Camera FINISH")
            return {'FINISHED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':  
            self.get_rotation()    

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
```

Now, everything works fine, but if I activate the "automatic keyframe insertion" button, it doesn't "record" anything. Why is this?

Comment: Is the issue with same object and properties being set by both, or does the auto record not work for all when the timer is running?

Comment: the auto record doesn't work for all.